# Vim statusline loses colors after reopening session

Tags: vim, statusline

I tweaked my statusline in vim a little, and started to like it. I use autosession.vim so when I reopen, I have the same files open, but the statusline loses all color settings. If I wipe buffer and reopen, the colors are back (or, if I source ~/.vimrc). 
Am I doing something wrong or is it just the nature of buffer, that after reopening session the statusline loses color settings? Pictures follow: 
[image: Colored]

[image: After reopening]

It might be worth mentioning that I use gvim on ArchLinux.

Comment: It might be worth showing the code were you set your status line in `.vimrc`

Comment: It's right in the picture, if you can't read it, view the image in new tab.

Comment: could you find out what settings restore the color? Probably just `statusline` but, why guess :) Perhaps you could show us what the setting looks like, in case it calls script functions as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can debug what overrides the statusline setting by doing

```
:verbose set statusline?
```

This will tell you were the value was last set

```
  statusline=.....
    Last set from C:\Program Files\Vim\_vimrc
```

Comment: This seems to be the right path, thanks. The autosession plugin sets the statusline again, but fails to include my custom colors settings. Is there a way to include colors right in the statusline string instead of defining them where autosession can't find them?

Comment: I solved my problem by injecting color settings into the autosession script so that they are executed on session restore. Your answer lead me to it, so I'll tag it as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your custom highlightings may get lost because of a `:syntax on` command when the session is restored. In addition to defining your custom highlightings like this:

```
:hi User1 guibg=Blue
```

add an autocmd that restores them:

```
:autocmd ColorScheme * hi User1 guibg=Blue
```

Comment: @d1001001 have you test this? If this one works, I suggest you accept this answer instead. Looks the sane route to me

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this add the following to your .vimrc for each user color:

```
autocmd SessionLoadPost * hi User1 guifg=#112005 guibg=#009099
```

SessionLoadPost triggers after the session file is loaded and  re-activates your custom colors.

Comment: Hi Adrian, unfortunately this doesnt work. :autocmd ColorScheme works

Answer (score 0):

### - Easiest stable solution -

#### Create a shell function to open a vim session and source your `.vimrc` after session finish loading, so you'll have all your seetings back:

Open you shell configuration file (`.bashrc` or `.zshrc`, etc) and write this function:

```
vims() {
  vim -S "$1" -c 'source ~/.vimrc'
}
```

After saving and sourcing the shell config file (or restarting the shell) you'll be always able to open a vim session with the command...

`vims mysession.vim`

...and it's done!  :)